# Hide Screen Label from React Native Drawer

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-drawer to show navigation drawer in my react native app. I am using two routes. first one is before login and second is for after login which is a drawer.
The problem I am facing is that If I add screen to drawer navigation then it also displays in drawer, but if i use stacknavigator then I cant access drawer at that screen.

here is my code for both navigations in my app.js:

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
        Dashboard: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
            params:{servUrl: url},
        },
       Profile: {
            screen: Profile
            params:{servUrl: url},
        },

    },
    {
        drawerPosition: 'right',
        initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
        drawerBackgroundColor: 'white',
        drawerWidth: 270,
        drawerType:'above',
        contentComponent: DrawerContentComponent,
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#259BCC',
            inactiveTintColor: '#939393',

        }

    });

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Login: { screen: LoginScreen ,
        navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
        navigationOptions: {
          headerShown: false,
        },
        params:{servUrl: url}
      },

        SignUp:{
          screen:SignUpScreen,
            navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false,
            },
            params:{servUrl: url}
        },
      

       AfterLogin:{
          screen:MyDrawerNavigator,
           params:{servUrl: url},
           navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
           navigationOptions: {
               headerShown: false,
           },
       },
       
        CallScreen:{
          screen:CallScreen,
            params:{servUrl:url},
            navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
            navigationOptions: {
                headerShown: false,
            },
        },
       
    }
);



const DrawerContentComponent = (props) => (

    <Container >

        <Header style={styles.drawerHeader}>
            <Body>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'} }>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.drawerImage}
                        source={require('./assets/logoWithoutText.png')} />
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:20,alignContent:'center',fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold',alignSelf:'center'}}>Test App</Text>
                </View>
            </Body>
        </Header>
        <Content >

            <DrawerItems  {...props} />
        </Content>

    </Container>

);
```

So Now I have some screens that I don't want to show in drawer but i want drawer to be still accessible there

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use react-navigation v5. It's pretty easy to use. You can check this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

You should use Stack navigator for login screen and Drawee navigator for the other one. I have not tried the code below but it should be working. You can access Drawer by calling `navigation.navigate('Root',{screen:'Home'})`

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={YourLoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
      <Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am able to call the drawer, but only in the screens which are in createDrawerNavigator function. the problem I have is that when i goto a screen which is not listed in drawer then i cant use drawer there.

Comment: I need a way to add screen to drawer but hide it from the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the drawer component with the screen name to the screen stack you will like to display the drawer on

Example

```
// Drawernav.js 
    
< Drawer navigator>
    
    < Drawer name='home' component={home}>
    < Drawer name='profile' component={profile}>
    
</ Drawer navigator>
```

```
//Stack Navigator.js
    
Import Drawernav from './Drawernav';
<Stack Navigator>
    
    < Stack screen name= "profile" component={Drawernav}>
    < Stack screen name= "post" component={post}>
    
</Stack Navigator>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.